# How to copy a file from my Windows laptop to an Ubuntu server while using PuTTY?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, scp

I have a remote server and I connect it via PuTTY software.
I've downloaded a file to my Downloads folder in my Windows OS laptop.
Now, I have to transfer this file to that remote server, using SCP Unix command.

Can someone bring me a clear and specified pattern or even an example of that command to my situation ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PSCP](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html) to copy files from Windows to Linux.

1. Download PSCP from putty.org
2. Open cmd in the directory with pscp.exe file
3. Type command `pscp source_file user@host:destination_file`

For example:-

> pscp C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\myfile.txt
>   admin@192.168.1.1:/home/path_to_the_folder/

Comment: If you (or whoever) installed using the recommended MSI (at the top of the chiark page, since maybe a decade now) all the tools (`pscp plink puttygen` etc) are already installed and you don't need to download anything more, and in your PATH so the directory doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pscp file user@remotehost:`

Comment: How do I find the remote host in Ubuntu server ?

Comment: It's the same as your putty remote server

Comment: And do how I find that ip address ?

Comment: How do you use PuTTY? The IP address or hostname used by pscp is the same as the one used in PuTTY.

Answer (score 1):

Try WinSCP [Get it here](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

You can login to the Linux server and transfer files using a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use WinSCP from the Windows machine to copy files to or from the linux server.

https://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Note that you will need to setup an ftp server on the linux server if you don't already have one running with this method.

Comment: Most Linux servers come with a built-in SSH server. That's all you need to connect with WinSCP (using SFTP protocol). – No need to setup an FTP server.